# Angular Promises with callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have the following 3 functions that I need to execute sequentially:

```
getSomeData1: ->
    @http.get("someRestUrl1")
getSomeData2: (param1, param2)->
    @http.get("someRestUrl2")
getSomeData3: ->
    @http.get("someRestUrl3")

getSomeData1().then(getSomeData2(param1, param2)).then(getSomeData3)
```

Now, if I want to attach a callback to the function getSomeData1 before calling the function getSomeData2, what would be the best way to do it?

The new callback does not contain any $http requests. It is a normal javascript function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a coffeescript guy, but in normal javascript, you can do something simple, just create an anonymous function that will first call your callback, then retrieve SomeData2:

```
getSomeData1: ->
    @http.get("someRestUrl1")
getSomeData2: ->
    @http.get("someRestUrl2")
getSomeData3: ->
    @http.get("someRestUrl3")

getSomeData1().then(function(){
    normalJsFunction();
   getSomeData2
}).then(getSomeData3)
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it is difficult to read/maintain. Let us say, we combine normalJsFunction() and getSomeData2() into a single function x. Then, we'll have getSomeData1().then(x).then(getSomeData3). The problem is that the new function will have the logic for both the callback for getSomeData1 as well as the function getSomeData2().

Comment: The callback and the getSomeData2 are already linked together, because they need to execute one after another. So call them in the same function X make sense. It doesn't add a dependency, it make the dependency between the two call explicit.

Comment: Ok, I've edited the question to reflect the actual scenario. The function getSomeData2 takes in 2 parameters. So, it is more like getSomeData1().then(x(param1, param2)).then(getSomeData3). The callback function normalJsFunction() requires access to the response of getSomeData1(). If I refactor as you suggest, how would I be able to access the response from inside x.

Comment: Pass someData1 Response to x function ? That one seems obvious too.

Comment: Yeah, I need to test this since response is not the only parameter going into x(). Will x(response, param1, param2) work?

Comment: Just tried, the following does not work:     getSomeData1().then(x(response, param1, param2)).then(getSomeData3).                                                     Function x is as follows,                                                                 x(response, param1, param2){                                   normalJsFunction(response);                                        getSomeData2(param1, param2);                                                                  }

Answer (score 1):

You could return a promise that resolves to a value in the callback that should be invoked before `getSomeData2`. I don't know CoffeeScript and I assume the $q service is available:

```
getSomeData1: ->
    @http.get("someRestUrl1")
getSomeData2: (param1, param2)->
    @http.get("someRestUrl2")
getSomeData3: ->
    @http.get("someRestUrl3")

function callback(data) {
    return $q.when(callbackReturnValue) 
}

getSomeData1().then(callback).then(getSomeData2(param1, param2)).then(getSomeData3)
```

Comment: Thanks. What if my callback function does not return anything?

Comment: Just return a dummy value like a boolean: `return $q.when(true)`

Comment: I just tried using $q.when(true). The function getSomeData2() is getting called before the callback() is complete.

Comment: Yes, because `getSomeData2` is called immediately here:
`getSomeData1().then(callback).then(getSomeData2(param1, param2)).then(getSomeData3)`
Do you use underscore/lodash?

A good solution could be to make a partial invocation of getSomeData2:

`getSomeData1().then(callback).then(_.partial(getSomeData2, param1, param2)).then(getSomeData3)`